# Can attribute table in map composer be changed from limit of 99 rows?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, table, limitations

I am using Qgis 2.2. I am about to create a cadastral index map, which are showing the parcels in specific gridcells, also there is an attribute table connected controlled by an atlas function. So by switching from gridcell to gridcell the attribute table automatically changes. Every gridcell has more than 99 parcels (Sometimes up to a few 100)

However, the attribute table in the map composer is limited to 99 rows, so not all parcels can be shown in the attribute table.

How can I increase the limit of 99 rows?

Comment: Which software package are you referring to? I'm guessing QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to let us know what GIS software and version you are using, please?  Also, include what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in QGIS 2.2, but for the upcoming QGIS 2.4 release (due June 20) I've bumped the maximum number of rows up to 999. If you're requiring this immediately, you could download a nightly development snapshot of QGIS for testing.